# (webrtc) chrome with mozilla not connecting please any idea how to do it

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I use (https://github.com/webRTC/webrtc.io-demo) and can't connect different browsers mozilla with mozilla  working good, chrome with chrome working good, but chrome with mozilla  not connecting please any idea how to do it

Comment: Can you describe the setup you are using to test this (separate machines, all on one machine)? What errors, if any, have you gotten? Which version of the browsers are you using?

Comment: I use last version of chrome and mozilla, and node server running on ubuntu 13.10,  I got an error (Argument 2 of mozRTCPeerConnection.createOffer is not an object.) only when I use on mozilla, after  it, I changed webrtc.io.js  on lines 324 and 302 null to function(){}, and mozilla with mozilla working now  but mozilla with chrome  not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project on GitHub does not look very active (the latest commits are about one year old).
Considering that webRTC is still developing, it would be surprising if there were not issues at all.
I'd recommend you to use another (more recent) webRTC demo, for example one of the demos provided by easyRTC: https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc

Furthermore, it is typically not possible to access the web cam with two browsers in parallel (just in case you are testing only using one machine).

Comment: Thanks, I wish create group contact in 5 users, I think I can edit  this  code  for group

Comment: yes, it should be manageable do adjust the easyRTC example code or just to write your own front end using the easyRTC framework